# iphone, ipad, universal app design, split view-based

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, universal

I want to build universal app.

Can I use split view-based application for iPad that work universal app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UISplitViewController is available exclusively on the iPad, so you can't use it on the iPhone. However, a universal app has separate XIBs for each category of device with the express intention of allowing you to provide entirely unrelated interfaces if appropriate. You therefore can use a UISplitViewController in a universal app, but only for the iPad part. You would possibly want to populate it with two controllers that are used directly on the iPhone.